# What is the inter-particle bonding in elemental mercury?

Tags: mercury

In most pure metals, there is metallic bonding where there exist positive monoatomic ions and a sea of electrons. Is this the same with mercury? If not, then in elemental (liquid) mercury, what kind of ions are present (polyatomic?)? Thanks.

Comment: Mercury is as good a metal as any other.

Comment: "positive monoatomic ions and a sea of electrons" - that not how metallic bonding works at all.

Comment: Metallic liquids are bonded similar to metallic solids, except that Bloch functions don't apply (although an average band structure does, much like amorphous solids).